# How can we prove that Gaussian integers are algebraic integers?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I heard in a lecture that every gaussian integer is in fact a root of a monic 2nd degree polynomial, it has been a day now and I can't figure this out.

Comment: Hint: Multiply by the conjugate

Comment: But that wouldn't be a polynomial, can you elaborate on that please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things to say here:

It's a general fact that the sum of two algebraic numbers/integers is also one and clearly, $bi = b\sqrt{-1}$ and $a$ are algebraic integers so $a+bi$ is one too.

But in this example, we can be more explicit: $a+bi$ is the root of the polynomial $x^2 - 2ax + (a^2+b^2) = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

In the second-degree polynomial $f(x) = \Big( x-(a+bi)\Big)\Big( x - (a-bi)\Big),$ the imaginary parts cancel out and the coefficients are then real integers.

Comment: Here's a slightly different way of looking at it. Suppose we want to solve the quadratic equation $(x-a)^2+b^2=0$ where $a$ and $b$ are real integers. $$ \begin{align} & (x-a)^2 + b^2 = 0. \\ {} \\ & (x-a)^2 = -b^2 \\ {} \\ & x-a = \pm bi \\ {} \\ & x = a\pm bi. \end{align} $$ Every Gaussian integer is the solution of a quadratic equation of this kind.